# Implementation through interface delegation not pass to descendant

Tags: interface, freepascal, delegation

Consider this interfaces and its implementations.

```
unit utest;

interface

{$MODE OBJFPC}

type

    IIntfA = interface
        procedure writeA();
    end;

    IIntfB = interface(IIntfA)
        procedure writeB();
    end;

    TADelegateClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IIntfA)
    public
        procedure writeA();
    end;

    TAClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IIntfA)
    private
        delegateA : IIntfA;
    public
        constructor create(const AInst : IIntfA);
        destructor destroy(); override;

        property A : IIntfA read delegateA implements IIntfA;
    end;

    TBClass = class(TAClass, IIntfB)
    public
        procedure writeB();
    end;

implementation

    procedure TADelegateClass.writeA();
    begin
        writeln('Implement IIntfA through delegation');
    end;

    constructor TAClass.create(const AInst : IIntfA);
    begin
        delegateA := AInst;
    end;

    destructor TAClass.destroy();
    begin
        inherited destroy();
        delegateA := nil;
    end;

    procedure TBClass.writeB();
    begin
        writeln('Implement IIntfB');
    end;

end.
```

Following program will not compile.

```
program test;

{$MODE OBJFPC}
uses
    utest;

var b : IIntfB;
begin
    b := TBClass.create(TADelegateClass.create());
    b.writeA();
    b.writeB();
end.
```

Free Pascal (version 3.0.4) complains

`Error: No matching implementation for interface method "writeA;" found`.

at line where `TBClass` is declared.

Of course, I can compile it successfully by implementing `writeA` either in `TAClass` or `TBClass` and call `writeA` method of `TADelegateClass` from there.

`TAClass` is concrete implementation of `IIntfA` interface through interface delegation but why `TBClass`, which is descendant of `TAClass`, is not considered a concrete implementation of `IIntfA` interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `TAClass` is concrete implementation of `IIntfA` interface through
>   interface delegation but why `TBClass`, which is descendant of `TAClass`,
>   is not considered a concrete implementation of `IIntfA` interface?

Short answer: it's not `IIntfA` that is the problem, it is `IIntfB` that is incomplete.

Long answer: Interface inheritance is C++ vtable inheritance, which is sometimes not intuitive.

In the example:

```
IIntfB = interface(IIntfA)
    procedure writeB();
end;
```

could actually be written as

```
IIntfB = interface
    procedure writeA();
    procedure writeB();
end;
```

When implementing multiple interfaces, common parts are not reused. The compiler sets up individual tables from the implementing methods, such as:

```
TADelegateClass:
   QueryInterface(IIntfA) =  Self.vtable_IIntfA
   vtable_IIntfA.writeA   <- Self.writeA

TAClass:
   QueryInterface(IIntfA) =  delegateA.vtable_IIntfA

TBClass:
   QueryInterface(IIntfA) =  inherited delegateA.vtable_IIntfA
   QueryInterface(IIntfB) =  vtable_IIntfB
   vtable_IIntfB.writeA   <- (this is missing!)
   vtable_IIntfB.writeB   <- Self.writeB
```

TBClass does indeed not have an implementation of `IIntfB.writeA`.
This can be verified by manually assigning a method to the specific interface and observe the error disappearing:

```
TBClass = class(TAClass, IIntfB)
public
    procedure IIntfB.writeA = writeB;
    // dummy method, shows IIntfB.writeA is missing
```

Sadly, I don't know of any way to tell the compiler to access a mapping from another interface. FWIW, Delphi has the same bug/shortcoming.